# How to send data to a SOAP Web Service using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, curl, soap

I have to send an XML of recent orders to a Web Service using PHP and I'm struggling to figure out how to connect to the web service, authorise and send the required data.

I have the Web Service URL:

```
https://xxxxx.co.uk/xxxxx/OrderRelay.svc?wsdl
```

a client code, username and password.

Do I use cURL to send the data or is there another method?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried SoapClient but get the error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://xxxxxx.co.uk/xxxx/OrderRelay.svc?wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Answer (score 0):

```
if (extension_loaded('soap'))
{
    $Username = "xxxxxx";
    $AccessKey = "xxxxxx";
 
     $url = "https://xxxxx.co.uk/xxxxx/OrderRelay.svc?wsdl";
    
    $options = array(
        'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
        'login' => $Username,
        'password' => $AccessKey,
        'trace' => 1,
        'exception' => 0,
    );
    try
    {
        $client = new SoapClient($url, $options);
                if($client){
                    
$client->Post_Orders(array("unique_Id"=>"$InvoiceNo", "itemNo"=>"$itemNo","_Quantity"=>"$itemQty","waiterNo"=>"$waiterNo","tableId"=>"$tableId","salesSection"=>"$itemSection"));  
                     
                }else{
                    echo"Failed";
                }
    }
    catch (SoapFault $soapFault)
    {
        echo "SOAP REQUEST FAILED :<br>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Php SOAP extention is not available";
}
```